# Can preseed automatically install Debian system with separate boot disk

Tags: partitioning, lvm, debian, preseed

I would like to automatically install a Debian system with multiple disks. There is `/dev/sda` for `/boot`, `/dev/sdb` for several LVs (for `/`, `/home`, etc.), and `/dev/sdc` for PostgreSQL's `/pddata`. I currently have a hard time understanding if and how this can be done with preseed.

FWIK `partman-auto/expert_recipe` can only partition single disks, so it could presumably serve for partitioning `/dev/sdb` (the disk with the most complex layout). The [usual workaround](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542327/how-do-i-preseed-partman-recipe-two-disks) for partitioning a second disk employs `preseed/late_command`, whoever since it runs commands [just before the install finishes](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/apbs05.html.en) it presumably cannot serve in relation to `/dev/sda` (nor `/dev/sdb`) because the installer must copy files there before it finishes. There is also `partman/early_command`, which sounds promising. However, it runs immediately before the partitioner starts, so before installation of the base system and hence before `fdisk` or `parted` are available. (At least that's what a quick experiment has suggested.) So it's back to the aforementioned limitations around partman, it would seem.

Am I missing something relevant here? Can preseed serve for automatically installing a Debian system with disk configurations such as mine?

Comment: We don't use preseed anymore in UBUNTU so you are actually asking about debian? We use "autoinstall" with netplan.

Comment: @Rinzwind I'll remove one mentioning of Ubuntu (in brackets) from the questions. It's otherwise already tagged `debian` and has Debian even in its title.

Comment: But we do not support debian ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use multiple disks with LVM, which you appear to plan to use.  From the [available documentation](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/debian-installer/blob/master/doc/devel/partman-auto-recipe.txt)

> When using the "lvm" autopartioning method, specific options are recognized in
> the recipe. Those enable multiple disks to be partitioned at once

I found [this blog post](https://followryan.wordpress.com/2019/01/10/auto-partitioning-multiple-drives-on-an-lvm-using-ubuntu-preseed/) that shares a full example config using `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`

```
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm

# These options remove any existing LVM and deploy a new system
# Without all of these set like this you can end up with errors
# when you try to reinstall a machine with existing volume groups
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      pvs ::                                                  \
              20480 750000 750000 ext4                        \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ lvm }                           \
                      device{ /dev/sda }                      \
                      vg_name{ system }                       \
              .                                               \
              1000000 1000000000 1000000000 ext4              \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ lvm }                           \
                      device{ /dev/sdb }                      \
                      vg_name{ data }                         \
              .                                               \
      system ::                                               \
              20480 20498 5000000 ext4                        \
                      $lvmok{ }                               \
                      lv_name{ root }                         \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
                      in_vg{ system }                         \
              .                                               \
              2048 2050 8192 linux-swap                       \
                      $lvmok{ }                               \
                      lv_name{ swap }                         \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
                      in_vg{ system }                         \
              .                                               \
      data ::                                                 \
              1000000 1000009 -1  ext4                        \
                      $lvmok{ }                               \
                      lv_name{ var }                          \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /data }                     \
                      in_vg{ data }                           \
              .                                               \
              100000 100001 500000 ext4                       \
                      $lvmok{ }                               \
                      lv_name{ datasnapshots }                \
                      \$defaultignore                         \
                      in_vg{ data }                           \
              .
```

I have not tried this myself.

Comment: This (if it works) will require LVM also to cover `/dev/sda`, which is not exactly what I was aiming for. I'll keep it in mind, though.

Comment: @rookie099 you can mix regular partitions with LVM partitions.  I'm not sure what limitations there are, but it might get you closer to your goal.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273741/how-do-i-preseed-mixed-lvm-and-regular-partitions